# Optimal compression quality for social media app?

Tags: ios, camera, compression, jpeg

Sorry if this has been addressed before, I searched it up and I couldn't seem to find a question like this. I am making a social media app, and I want to preserve the quality of the images as much as possible. To make a data representation of the image I am using "UIImageJPEGRepresentation" and I would like to know what an optimal setting for the compression quality is.

One big consequence of setting the quality below 1 is that the image uploads to my server in much less time. I have experimented with the compression and to me I can't really tell the difference between 0.6 and 1 unless I zoom in on a computer, but I just wanted to know if there was a number or range that would produce favorable results.

Comment: While I've no doubt that there has been some formalized research on this (which would be an off-topic/off-site resource request), Stack Overflow is not a place to try and solicit opinions or ask open-ended questions.

Comment: If there is research I think many other people could benefit from this. I didn't ask this question purely for an opinion, but rather to help anybody else who might have the same question/be in a similar situation. But, I have updated my question to make it less of an opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the interesting and evolving format is Webp format that Google has introduced. [This](http://www.cnet.com/news/facebook-tries-googles-webp-image-format-users-squawk/) article suggests that Facebook is also trying to use this format. To answer the exact question as to how much to compress please note the following:

-Format of the image(I assume yours is JPEG)

-Compression technique(Lossy or Lossless)

-Target devices(I assume yours is mobile)

Considering above parameters(and [more](https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/project/f06/aguilera_rpt.pdf)) and looking at the [dimensions of all social networking sites](http://stosu.com/dimensions-of-images-required-for-social-networking-sites/) I suggest you to get the compression level high enough such that you can see a difference in the image quality on the computer, that way you would have found an optimal level, remember lower the better till it degrades. Additionally you can find the information at [this](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jpeg-optimization-guide/).